# Remove/Uninstall Python 3.5

Tags: python, uninstall, make

I am trying to uninstall Python 3.5. I have tried this up till now:

```
sudo make clean
sudo make uninstall
sudo -n install
```

These commands don't remove Python 3.5 completely. I want to keep 3.4 as it is built in (Ubuntu 14.04). I want to specifically remove 3.5. Any suggestions?

---

Steps I used to install 3.5:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/Python-3.5.0.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.5.0.tgz
cd Python-3.5.0
./configure
sudo make install
```

Comment: Please describe in detail how you installed Python 3.5. The uninstallation process depends on that.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.5? The commands you say you used apply to a package installed from source, and must be used in the package's source directory.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have edited the question.Please take a look.

Comment: And why exactly do you think that the above commands you tried do not uninstall Python 3.5?

Answer (score 5):

A manually installed Python-[any-version] has no uninstall. The only method is to delete the files.

Suggest : `cd Python-3.5.0/ && sudo make install 2>&1 | tee install.log.txt`

Analyze the install.log.txt, and decide if it is possible to delete the installed files, without disturbing the default python3.5 ( /usr/lib/python3.5, etc.) and python3 : /usr/lib/python3, etc.